# iOS Imagemagick to apply border color in iPhone

Tags: ios, imagemagick

I have successfully ported ImageMagick in my iPhone Application, everything seems to be working. I need to apply one filter for border color. I have written using Pixelwand, however its not been showing border color. Below is my code.

```
PixelWand *color = NewPixelWand();
PixelSetColor(color, "PixelGetMagenta");
status = MagickSetImageBorderColor(magick_wand, color);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PixelSetColor's](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/pixel-wand.php#PixelSetColor) second parameter is expecting color name, not a  method name. Example "magenta", "#FF00FF", or "rgb(255,0,255)". The `MagickBooleanType` would return `MagickFalse` when calling `PixelSetColor(color, "PixelGetMagenta");`, as setting a color named "PixeGetMagenta" would fail. [PixelGetMagenta](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/pixel-wand.php#PixelGetMagenta) is usally used with [PixelGetMagentaQuantum](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/pixel-wand.php#PixelGetMagentaQuantum) when working directly with color packets.

```c
MagickBooleanType status;
PixelWand *color = NewPixelWand();
status = PixelSetColor(color, "magenta");
// Error handle if status == MagickFalse
status = MagickSetImageBorderColor(magick_wand, color);
// Error handle if status == MagickFalse
status = MagickBorderImage(wand,color,10,10);
// Error handle if status == MagickFalse
```